# Set rootController programmatically in xcode 11 for iOS10+ supporting application

Tags: ios

I have setup the rootController in SceneDelegate and it was working fine.

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

    let contentView = ContentView()

    if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
        self.window = window
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

However, when I change the target version to iOS10+, it shows error

[image]

If I add an attribute to enclosing class, will it be able to load rootController on iOS13 below version?

Please guide me with the best approach to handle this scenario.

Thanks!

Comment: scene delegate is only available after iOS 13. if you wouldn't set a window from appdelegate it will not work bellow iOS 13.

Comment: That correct, Is there any way to resolve this. Because my application should support version below 13 as well.

Comment: You can use if #available(iOS 13.0, *) { } else { } condition to distinguish code for bellow versions.

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this with two approaches:

### First Approach:

SceneDelegate is introduced from iOS 13 and Xcode 11. So this issue will only occur if you are creating a new project with Xcode 11 and keep the target version below iOS 13.

If you want to create the application without SceneDelegate the best way is to create the project in Xcode 10, with which you will not need to deal with SceneDelegate and you can move further AppDelegate.

So, in this case, you will have the window property in AppDelegate itself and it will work for iOS 13 and below versions.

### Second Approach:

If you want iOS 13 features like multiple windows for iPadOS, Please refer to this [here](https://www.donnywals.com/add-ios-12-support-to-a-new-xcode-11-project/)

In my view, you should go with the second approach, which will provide iOS 13 users with all the new features(iOS 13 supporting features) in the application.